# Linq query join three tables with an inner join and a left join in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have three tables:  `Form`, `User` and `Address`.

There is no relationship between `User` and `Form` I know but this is really old database and they don't want us to change the table structure.

Form table

```
FormId
AddressID
FormName 
etc..
```

Relationship

```
UserandAddress
```

So, `User` and `Address` have a many-to-many relationship.

I have this function `GetUser()` which returns a list of strings which contain the `AddressId`.

Now I just need to fetch those `Form`s which have these `AddressId`s.

I tried something like this:

```cs
var _objA = (from _Form in _context.Form.Where(c => c.IsDeleted == 0).ToList()
     join _Address in _context.Address.ToList()
     on _Address.ServiceCaseManager equals _Form.NUserId.ToString() //as you know i have list of address so I guess I have to use Any() 
     select new 
            {
            }
```

Comment: If you have a function that returns a `List<string>` which contains the properties of User and Address. Then why not Deserialize that `List<string>` into a `List<User/Address>` then perform the query join

Comment: Please try to avoid calling the `ToList`  operator inside your query. You materialize your records in memory before you join them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this function GetUser() which returns a list of strings which contain the AddressId

Not sure what this method does. Does it return a list of strings, where every string contains one AddressId of the User? Of which User? of all Users?

Well, I don't think we can use this method. Let's focus on your table relations.

So you have `Users` and `Addresses`, Every User has zero or more Addresses, and every Address has zero or more Users. A standard many-to-many relation using the junction table `UserAndAddress`.

There is one-to-many relationship between Addresses and Forms: Every Address has zero or more Forms; every Form belongs to exactly one Address, namely the Address that foreign key AddressId refers to.

So each User has many Addresses, each Address has many Forms.

> Whenever you want to query "items with their many sub-items", like "Customers with their Orders", "Schools with their Students", or "Users with their Addresses, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin).

> If you have a one-to-many and you want to start at the "many" side to get the one element that it has, like the "Order with the Customer who made this Order", or the "Student with the School he attends", use [Queryable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join).

You want to get "Users, each User with their Addresses, each Address with its Forms". Because Users - Addresses is a many-to-many, you need an in-between step: use GroupJoin to get the "Users with their zero or more UserAddresses".

You know that every UserAddress has exactly one Address, namely the Address that the foreign key `UserAddress.AddressId` refers to.

After you've got all Addresses of the User, you can use a simple GroupJoin to get all Forms of the Address.

Every User has many addresses. Start at the "One" side of the One-to-Many: use GroupJoin

```
var ussersWithAddressesAndForms = dbContext.Users.Where(user => ...)
    .GroupJoin(dbContext.UserAddresses,
    user => user.Id,
    userAddress => userAddress.UserId,

    (user, userAddressesOfThisUser) => new
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        ...

        // One-to-Many between Address and UserAddresses,
        // start at the "many" side: use Join
        Addresses = userAddressesOfThisUser.Join(dbContext.Addresses,
            userAddress => userAddress.AddressId,
            address => address.Id,

            (userAddress, address) => new
            {
                 Id = address.Id,
                 Street = address.Street,
                 ...

                 // Get all Forms of this Address that have a foreign key referring to this address
                 Forms = dbContext.Forms
                     .Where(form => form.AddressId == address.Id)
                     .Select(form => new
                     {
                         Id = form.Id,
                         Date = form.Date,
                         ...
                     })
                     .ToList(),
            })
            .ToList()<
});
```

Result: All Users, each with his zero or more Addresses, each Address with its zero or more Forms.

Select only the properties that you want. If you don't want a three layer result (Users with their Addresses with their Forms), use SelectMany to flatten it: "Users with their Forms"

Comment: Nice explanation, but very big. GroupJoin in lambda syntax is a nightmare in complex queries even in your sample. IMHO better to teach how to use LINQ Query syntax to achieve the same results. After second GroupJoin this query will looks like a non-refactoriable mess.